# How to get the String Value of a Json element on the Same line in F#

Tags: f#

I have some code that I would like to put on the same line instead of having separate variable ( maybe pipe? )

```
    let! creditText = row.EvalOnSelectorAsync("div.moneyout","node => node.innerText") |> Async.AwaitTask
    let JSonElementString = creditText.Value.GetString()
```

I would like to have something like:

```
let! creditText = row.EvalOnSelectorAsync("div.moneyout","node => node.innerText") |> Async.AwaitTask |> (fun js -> js.Value.GetString)
```

I can see what is happening - at the point of the function the variable is still async.  How can I make it pipe the result through to a function on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand why you want to do this. The code is perfectly readable and succinct when it is written as two lines. Condensing it into a single line only makes it harder to understand.

That said, if you wanted to do this, the best option would be to have a *map* operation for either `Async<T>` or `Task<T>`. This exists in various libraries, but you can also easily define it yourself:

```
module Async = 
  let map f a = async { 
    let! r = a
    return f a }
```

Using this, you can now write:

```
let! creditText = 
  row.EvalOnSelectorAsync("div.moneyout","node => node.innerText") 
  |> Async.AwaitTask 
  |> Async.map (fun creditText -> creditText.Value.GetString())
```

But as I said above, I think this is a bad idea and your two-line version is nicer.

Comment: Thanks.  It was more about keeping it in the same variable than the same line and having the ability to pipe it along to other functions as well if need be.

Comment: Where is Async.map ?  from a different library?

Comment: There's an implementation in my answer. You could also get it from a library like FSharpx.Async: http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Async/reference/fsharpx-control-asyncextensions.html

Comment: There is also a request to make it part of the standard library: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/859